# How to change specific item button name by clicking the button in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have multiple item cards on a page, I want to change only a specific item/card button `" Add Favt"` to `"Remove Favt`" when the user clicks on the `"Add Favt"` button. But in my case, all of the card button names change when clicked on only one card button.

**Here is my approach:**

```
const Listitem = ({ posts }) => {
    const [btn, setBtn] = useState('Add Favt');
    var arr = [];
    const click = (index) => {
        arr.push(posts[index]);
        console.log(arr);
        localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify({ arr }));
        if (btn === 'Add Favt') {
            setBtn('Remove Favt');
        } else {
            setBtn('Add Favt');
        }
    };
    return (
        <div className="fav-content">
            <ul className="card">
                {posts.map((item, index) => {
                    console.log(item._id);
                    return (
                        <li key={item._id}>
                            <button onClick={() => click(index)}>{btn}</button>
                            <div className="post">
                                <h1>Name: {item.name}</h1>
                                <p>Bio: {item.bio}</p>
                                <a href={item.link}>Link: {item.link}</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    );
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};
```

> How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be one possible solution to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

**Please view the snippet in Full Page**

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Listitem = ({posts, ...props}) => {
  // track whether each card is is favorite or not
  const [isFavorite, setIsFavorite] = useState({});
  
  // when button clicked, flip card from favorite
  const handleClick = e => {
    const id = e.target.id;
    setIsFavorite(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      [id]: !prev[id]
    }))
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="fav-content">
      List of favorites: {
        posts
        .filter(({_id}) => [_id] in isFavorite && isFavorite[_id])
        .map(({name}) => name)
        .join()
      }
      <ul className="card">
        {posts.map(item => (
          <li key={item._id}>
            <button
              id={item._id}
              onClick={handleClick}
            >
              {
                isFavorite[item._id]
                ? 'Remove Fav'
                : 'Add Fav'
              } {item.name}
            </button>
            <div className="post">
                <h4>Name: {item.name}</h4>
                <p>Bio: {item.bio}</p>
                <a href={item.link}>Link: {item.link}</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          )
        )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

const itemsList = [
  {_id: 1, name: 'item 1', bio: 'bio 1', link: 'link 1'},
  {_id: 2, name: 'item 2', bio: 'bio 2', link: 'link 2'},
  {_id: 3, name: 'item 3', bio: 'bio 3', link: 'link 3'},
  {_id: 4, name: 'item 4', bio: 'bio 4', link: 'link 4'},
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    DEMO
    <Listitem posts={[...itemsList]}/>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("rd")
);
```

```css
.fav-content { width: fit-content; padding: 5px 15px; }
.card { background-color: #DDDDFF; margin: 5px 15px; }
.post { background-color: #FFFFDD; margin: 5px 15px; }
```

```html
<div id="rd" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments have been provided in the above code snippet.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. But I have another function called click(index) that was for storing data on local storage, if I try to do the same task as click(index) in handleClick() it doesn't work. Any suggestion on how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, can be done like so (within `handleClick`): `localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(posts.filter(({_id}) => (_id === id || ([_id] in isFavorite && isFavorite[_id])))));`. Please add this just below: `const id = e.target.id;`. However, why do you need to update local-storage each & every time user selects/de-selects. It may be better to update it once the user confirms their choice.

Answer (score 2):

You are using btn state variable for each button. setting btn in state will reflect in all of them. Make a separate component for this.

```
    <button onClick={() => click(index)}>{btn}</button>
    <div className="post">
        <h1>Name: {item.name}</h1>
        <p>Bio: {item.bio}</p>
        <a href={item.link}>Link: {item.link}</a>
    </div>
```

Maintain a local state in new component for status of individual item.